# Initialize a type variable with dynamic / concrete type

Tags: scala, types, typeclass, implicit, type-members

I am learning Scala and I was trying to create a type class to solve the "Every animal eats food, but the type of food depends on the animal" problem. I have an `Eats` type class with context bounds:

```
trait Eats[A <: Animal, B <: Edible]

object Eats {
    def apply[A, B]: Eats[A, B] = new Eats[A, B] {}
}
```

with both `Animal` and `Edible` being abstract classes. The (reduced) `Animal` interface looks something like this

```
abstract class Animal {
    type This // concrete type
    def eat[A <: Edible](food: A)(implicit e: Eats[This, B]) = // ...
}
```

My goal is to allow calls in the form of `animal.eat(food)` only if there is an instance (an implicit value in scope) for the given type of animal and food. For this I created an `EatingBehaviour` object which basically contains instances for all relations. E. g. to declare that cows eat grass I add the line

```
implicit val cowEatsGrass = Eats[Cow, Grass]
```

similar to how you would write `instance Eats Cow Grass` in Haskell. However, Now i need to specify the abstract type `This` for all subtypes of the Animal class for the signature in the `Animal` interface to work:

```
class Cow extends Animal { type This = Cow }
```

which is redundant.

**Hence my question**: Can I somehow initialize the type variable `This` in `Animal` so that this always reflects the concrete type, similar to how I could ask for the dynamic type using `getClass`?

Comment: Do you need `eat` to be a method of `Animal` or can it be on another object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem doesn't occur if you pass the first operand `a: A` to a method / class constructor that has the opportunity to infer the externally visible type `A`:

```
trait Animal
trait Eats[A <: Animal, B <: Animal]

object Eats {
    def apply[A <: Animal, B <: Animal]: Eats[A, B] = new Eats[A, B] {}
}

implicit class EatsOps[A <: Animal](a: A) {
    def eat[B <: Animal](food: B)(implicit e: Eats[A, B]) = 
      printf(s"%s eats %s\n", a, food)
}

case class Cat() extends Animal
case class Bird() extends Animal
case class Worm() extends Animal

implicit val e1 = Eats[Cat, Bird]
implicit val e2 = Eats[Bird, Worm]

val cat = Cat()
val bird = Bird()
val worm = Worm()

// c eat c // nope
cat eat bird
// c eat w // nope

// b eat c // nope
// b eat b // nope
bird eat worm 

// w eat c // nope
// w eat b // nope
// w eat w // nope
```

Here, `EatsOps[A <: Animal]` can first infer what `A` is, then in `eat[B <: Animal]` it can infer what `B` is, and using information about both `A` and `B` insert the correct implicit. There are no type members, and nothing has to be done when extending `Animal`.

It's a bit of an X-solution to an XY-problem. And, yeah, I reused `Animal` instead of `Food`...

---

**Update**

If you want to access some private methods of a particular `Animal` implementation when invoking `eat`, the usual way to do this would be to move all the essential functionality into the `Eats` trait, and then provide instances of `Eats` in the companion object of a specific `Animal`. For example, here is how we could let a `Cat` do its uncanny `private` stuff before actually eating a `Bird`:

```
trait Eats[A <: Animal, B <: Animal] {
  def apply(a: A, food: B): Unit
}

object Eats {
    def apply[A <: Animal, B <: Animal]: Eats[A, B] = new Eats[A, B] {
      def apply(animal: A, food: B) = println(s"${animal} eats ${food}")
    }
}

implicit class EatsOps[A <: Animal](animal: A) {
    def eat[B <: Animal](food: B)(implicit e: Eats[A, B]) = e(animal, food)
}

case class Cat() extends Animal {
  private def privateCatMethod(b: Bird): Unit = {}
}

object Cat {
  implicit val catsEatBirds: Eats[Cat, Bird] = new Eats[Cat, Bird] {
    def apply(c: Cat, b: Bird): Unit = {
      c.privateCatMethod(b)
      println(s"{c} eats {b}")
    }
  }
}
```

The rest of the code would remain unchanged, except that one doesn't need `e1: Eats[Cat, Bird]` any more.

Comment: Thank you very much, I already forgot about implicit classes :)

Comment: Though since EatOps is a separate class now, i don't see a possibility for `eat` to access protected or private members of the `Animal` trait. How would you go about solving this problem? Is there an "idiomatic" scala way to do this?

Comment: @NiklasVest Idiomatic is to put `EatsOps` into companion object of `Animal`.

Comment: @NiklasVest Although `private[this]` members of `Animal` will be still inaccessible for `eat`.

Comment: @DmytroMitin I assume you meant that instances of `Eats` for `Cat` should be moved to the companion object for `Cat`. Updated.

Comment: @NiklasVest Since it's the `Eats[A, B]` that is now doing all the work (the `.eat(...)` invocation being mostly syntactic sugar), you would have to provide an instance of `Eats` somewhere where you have access to the private methods of a particular `Animal` - that would usually be the companion object. See the update.

Comment: Thanks for the update! I have one last question now. Say I want to provide a final implementation in the abstract class (e. g. some sort of template method). Is there a way I can simply delegate `Eats.apply` to `Animal.eat` only if that implicit exists? I know at this point I should be asking myself why I would even want to achieve this but I am just trying to take the language apart, not to create a mastercraft API :)

Comment: @NiklasVest I don't really understand your last question, I'm afraid. In my proposal, `Animal` still doesn't have any method at all, there is no `Animal.eat`, there are only `Eats`-instances and some syntactic sugar that looks like `eat`-method. I also don't understand the condition *"only if that implicit exists"* - do you want to provide a default implementation of `eat` in `Animal`, and then choose more specific `Eats` if available? That could be solved with some variance annotations and prioritized implicits, but that would get increasingly complicated.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Yes I wanted to achieve something along those lines :) Animal would have an `eat` implementation only for foods for which there exists an `Eats` instance and this implementation would be final or at least I would not have to override it in every subclass as you now had to in your `Cat` class for example. The default behavior in my implementation is to just reduce the hunger and that probably won't change for additional animals.

Answer (score 2):

Normally in type-level programming type `This` is defined in subtypes manually. For example

https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/ast/Node.scala#L129

https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/master/slick/src/main/scala/slick/ast/Node.scala#L151

etc.

Also one can use macro annotation to generate type `This` automatically

```
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

class This extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro thisMacro.impl
}

object thisMacro {
  def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    annottees match {
      case q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }" :: tail =>
        val tparams1 = tparams.map {
          case q"$_ type $name[..$_] >: $_ <: $_" => tq"$name"
        }
        q"""
            $mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self =>
              type This = $tpname[..$tparams1]
              ..$stats
            }

            ..$tail
          """

      case q"$mods object $tname extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$body }" :: Nil =>
        q"""
            $mods object $tname extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self =>
              type This = $tname.type
              ..$body
            }
          """

      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "not class or object")
    }

  }
}

    @This
    class Cow extends Animal 

//Warning:scalac: {
//  class Cow extends Animal {
//    def <init>() = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    };
//    type This = Cow
//  };
//  ()
//}
```

Unfortunately, since annotation can change only its annottee, we can't annotate only the abstract class so that type `This` will be generated for all subclasses.

Comment: I love how you completely escalated with the macro stuff! Haven't gotten to that point in my scala adventure but thanks anyway :)

Comment: @NiklasVest I published small library at github https://github.com/DmytroMitin/AUXify You can try annotation `This` from there.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way for an abstract type to know the concrete type is to pass the concrete type up to the abstract type (this is called "F-bounded polymorphism"):

```
abstract class Animal[This <: Animal[_]] {
  def eat[A <: Edible](food: A)(implicit e: Eats[This, A]) = ???
}

class Cow extends Animal[Cow]
```

The `Animal` class now knows the concrete type on which the `eat` method is defined.

Note that you need to tweak the references to `Animal` to add the type parameter:

```
trait Eats[A <: Animal[_], B <: Edible]

object Eats {
  def apply[A <: Animal[_], B <: Edible]: Eats[A, B] = new Eats[A, B]
}
```

Comment: `abstract class Animal { type This <: Animal }` is also kind of F-bounded polymorphism.

Comment: `class Whatever extends Animal[Animal[_]];
class Cow extends Animal[Whatever]` compiles with this definition. Don't think it was intended? I'm somehow missing the recursion in this F-bounded definition. Also, `new Eats[A, B] {}` doesn't want to compile without the `{}`-body.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin So what's the problem? `class Whatever extends Animal {
    type This = Animal
  }` `class Cow extends Animal {
    type This = Whatever
  }` compiles too.

Comment: @DmytroMitin If you want it to compile, then there is no problem. But I assumed that one doesn't want `class Cow extends Animal[Crocodile]` to compile, because a `Cow` would probably choke when you try to feed an antelope to it. And without the recursively tied knot `Animal[A <: Animal[A]]`, it's not proper F-bounded polymorphism. So, I assume it should be `Animal[This <: Animal[This]]`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Right. It should be either `abstract class Animal[This <: Animal[This]]` or `abstract class Animal { self => type This <: Animal { type This = self.This } }`.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative approach but this is similar to my solution by favoring parameterization over object-oriented abstraction. With `class Cow extends Animal[Cow]` I - again - supply redundant information.

Answer (score 1):

Consider type class implementation like so

```
  sealed trait Food
  case object Grass extends Food
  case object Meat extends Food

  sealed trait Animal
  case object Cow extends Animal
  case object Lion extends Animal

  @scala.annotation.implicitNotFound("${A} does not eat ${F}. Yuk!")
  trait CanEat[A <: Animal, F <: Food] {
    def eat(animal: A, food: F)
  }

  implicit val cowCanEatGrass = new CanEat[Cow.type, Grass.type] {
    def eat(animal: Cow.type, food: Grass.type) = println("yum yum yum...delicious")
  }

  def eat[A <: Animal, F <: Food](animal: A, food: F)(implicit canEat: CanEat[A, F]) = 
    canEat.eat(animal, food)
```

which outputs

```
  eat(Cow, Grass) // yum yum yum...delicious
  eat(Cow, Meat)  // error: Cow.type does not eat Meat.type. Yuk!
```